# Drawing an image in this method?

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        NumberOfBets++;

        if ((e.X >= 40 && e.X <= 125) && (e.Y >= 0 && e.Y <= 26))
        {
            bettingStatus[0]++;
            for (int x; x < 10; x++)
            {
                Graphics graphic = (???)
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to draw an image in this MouseDown method. I have NO clue what goes in the "(???)" part.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a Graphics object for the pictureBox1 control.
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
```

Read more: [MSDN: Graphics Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)

You should draw in the Paint event, because if you don't, you will loose your drawings if the control is repainted. The PaintEventArgs passed to the Paint event handler has a Property named Graphics (of type System.Drawing.Graphics) which you can draw on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `Graphics` from somewhere, probably `pictureBox1` in your case:

```
Graphics graphic = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
```

...But are you sure you want to be drawing in a `MouseDown` event handler? It won't be repainted if any part gets redrawn. You'd probably be better off doing all your drawing in a `Paint` event handler and setting a flag in `MouseDown` instead. Then invalidate the region you want to be redrawn to draw the new image.

Or, if your images are going to be more static, you can create a `Bitmap`, draw on that, then set the `Image` of your `PictureBox` to point to the `Bitmap` instead. For example:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 100);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
//do drawing here
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```